# Github workflow job not triggered while dependent on other job

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to achieve a flow with a job dependency tree based on `needs` and `if`

This is the workflow file, and my problem is that the job4 is not being triggered even when the job3 is being executed successfully.

I can't find any documentation explaining what is happening, but it seems that the `needs` tree that is being built behind the scenes is not matching the job4, because the `needs` on the job3 is not completed (is forced by the `if`)

I have a workaround to solve this flow using job outputs, but I was wondering why the simple example is not working. Can anyone explain me why?

Thanks

```
name: Test Workflow

on:
  push:


jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo Job1


  job2:
    if: cancelled()
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo Job2


  job3:
    if: always()
    needs: [job1, job2]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo Job3


  job4:
    needs: job3
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo Job4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dependent jobs must succeed. So jon your job 4 depdends on the job 3 it must that job 3 and all it's need must be succeded.

Please check this [GitHub issue - Job-level "if" condition not evaluated correctly if job in "needs" property is skipped](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/491#issuecomment-850884422).

I assume that in your case even if you forced job 3 to run the result is not success but something different. Thus job 4 is not run.

You probably need sth like this on job 4.

```yaml
if: |
      always() &&
      (needs.job3.result == 'success' || needs.job3.result == 'skipped')
```

Comment: Thanks @krzysztof-madej that is was I though. I need to use outputs from the jobs to check for success.

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?